# Redis cache for apollo server v4

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redis, apollo-client, apollo-server

I have the below query

```
query GetMajorIncidents {
            getMajorIncidents {
                category
                subcategory
                dv_cmdb_ci
                dv_state
                major_incident_state
                number
                opened_at
                short_description
                u_clientpriority
                u_global_priority
                u_clientpriority
                u_incident_end
                u_incident_start
                u_incident_commander
                dv_u_business_segments
                dv_u_communication_category
                duration {
                    days
                    hours
                    minutes
                    seconds
                    milliseconds
                }
            }
        }
```

I have put the caching code in the resolver **(cannot paste the code)** with the info param set to

```
 info.cacheControl.setCacheHint({
                        maxAge: 300,
                        scope: 'PUBLIC',
                    });
```

**The caching is not happening in redis. **

**Now, if I remove the duration object from the above query, it starts caching the results. I'm not sure why this is happening.**

My schema looks like:

```
type Data {
category: String
                subcategory: String
                dv_cmdb_ci: String
                dv_state: String
                major_incident_state: String
                number: String
                opened_at: String
                short_description: String
                u_clientpriority: String
                u_global_priority: String
                u_clientpriority: String
                u_incident_end: String
                u_incident_start: String
                u_incident_commander: String
                dv_u_business_segments: String
                dv_u_communication_category: String
duration: Duration
}

type Duration {
days: Int
      hours: Float
      minutes: Float
      seconds: Float
      milliseconds: Float
}
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!!! I was able to fix this by providing the cache params to the duration schema